# Topological Quantum Field Theory diagrams with pstricks or tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`tqft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tqft)  — Blog: [The TQFT Package](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/the-tqft-package/)

I'm going to write a brief note about [topological quantum field theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory), so I need to draw some copies of the "[pair of pant](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Pair_of_pants_cobordism_%28pantslike%29.svg)s"... I'm wondering if there's a simple way to obtain such an object with tikz or PStricks; the challenge is that I would like to create a "modular" set of objects to assembly in a second moment: drawn the pair of pants, and another object, I don't want to recreate everything to obtain the juxtaposition of the two.

Edit: [this](http://mat.uab.es/~kock/TQFT/trailer.pdf) is what I want to obtain.

[image]

Comment: I guess you'd regard http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/documents/smooth_chern.1.pdf as overkill!

Comment: You should include the drawings available at your links as part of your question, so there is no need to follow the links.

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: I was serious when I said it was overkill!  I know the sort of diagram that you want, I was just being a little silly posting that link (plus I'm quite pleased with that picture).

Comment: @ipavlic: you completely right, sorry...

@Andrew: Even if that drawing din't help, I found [this](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/documents/smooth_chern.beamer.pdf) beautiful pdf :)

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: Thanks.  I'm quite pleased with that talk.

Comment: There's now a style file for this available at: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/tqft.sty (no documentation yet, though)

Comment: And a picture and sample file over here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/tikz-pgf-answer-package-part-2/1314#1314

Comment: I've reworked the package file and written some documentation.  If you use it, please let me know what works and what doesn't!

Comment: Are your notes on TQFT available yet? I'd be quite interested in them.

Comment: Several years passed, I've used the notes and lost them. But they did not contain anything different, or anything new from other sources on the topics (cobordism.pdf, [this thesis](http://algant.eu/documents/theses/zhao.pdf), etc.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Update (2011-05-06):** A reworked version of this code is available for download at: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files as the file `tqft.dtx`.  To generate the package file and the documentation, run `pdflatex tqft.dtx`.  This file is part of the package proposed at [What are your favourite TikZ/PGF answers?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/what-are-your-favourite-tikz-pgf-answers) which will be released on CTAN in due course.

---

What follows is an example, based on a previous version of this answer.  I *hope* that I've edited it correctly to reflect the current methodology of the package, but if there's a conflict, refer to the package documentation.

Right, here's a more comprehensive solution.  The main hassle was setting things up so that one can change the direction of the "flow" of the cobordisms.  That's done by a key `tqft/flow` which, at the moment, can take one of the directions `north`, `south`, `east`, and `west` (default is `south`).  This rotates stuff so that the incoming to outgoing directions are in the right direction.  It also reflects things so that the boundary numbering is always from top to bottom or from left to right.

The node types are, with the anchors that they define (all define `centre` and `center` so I haven't listed them) (**update** the anchors have been reworked a little so that all now define `incoming boundary n` and `outgoing boundary n` for `n` a reasonable integer (less than `10` by default)):

- `tqft/pair of pants`: `incoming boundary 1`, `outgoing boundary 1`, `outgoing boundary 2`
- `tqft/reverse pair of pants`: `incoming boundary 1`, `incoming boundary 2`, `outgoing boundary 1`
- `tqft/cylinder to prior`: `incoming boundary 1`, `outgoing boundary 1`; this is a cylinder that is skewed in so that the outgoing boundary is shifted towards the lower numbered boundary components by just the right amount to fit with a `tqft/pair of pants`
- `tqft/cylinder to next`: `incoming boundary 1`, `outgoing boundary 1`; this is a cylinder that is skewed in so that the outgoing boundary is shifted towards the higher numbered boundary components by just the right amount to fit with a `tqft/pair of pants`
- `tqft/cylinder`: `incoming boundary 1`, `outgoing boundary 1`; this is a straight cylinder
- `tqft/cap`: this "caps off" a boundary component
- `tqft/cup`: this starts a boundary component

Global keys:

- `tqft/flow`: see above
- `tqft/cobordism height`: this is the separation between the levels in the cobordism (aka the height of the pair of pants, etc)
- `tqft/boundary separation`: this is the separation between the centres of the boundary components (aka the width of the pair of pants, etc)
- `tqft/circle width`: the boundary components are ellipses, this sets the horizontal axis (relative to the cobordism)
- `tqft/circle depth`: this sets the vertical axis of the boundary ellipses

And here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tqft}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/flow=east]
\node[tqft/pair of pants,draw] (a) {};
\node[tqft/reverse pair of pants,draw,anchor=incoming boundary 1] (b) at (a.outgoing boundary 2) {};
\node[tqft/cylinder to next,draw,anchor=incoming boundary 1] (c) at (a.outgoing boundary 1) {};
\node[tqft/cylinder to next,draw,anchor=outgoing boundary 1] (e) at (b.incoming boundary 2) {};
\path (b.outgoing boundary 1) ++(1.5,1) node[font=\Huge] {\(=\)};
\path (b.outgoing boundary 1) ++(3,0) node[tqft/reverse pair of pants,draw,anchor=incoming boundary 2] (e) {};
\node[tqft/pair of pants,draw,anchor=incoming boundary 1] (f) at (e.outgoing boundary 1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's the result:

[image: tqft with tikz]

Comment: This is wonderful!

Comment: I obtained any possible permutation and combination of pants, but... Telling the truth i blindely copypasted your code: I'm a bit lost in it so I don't see how to modify things to create other shapes. :( Could you please write how to obtain cups and caps? Thanks a lot

Comment: Decomposition of a connected sum of tori can be drawn with a "chain" of pants: this is what I tried to do
`\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[scale=.5, pair of pants,draw,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=2cm,rotate=90] (a) {};

\node[scale=.5,pair of pants,draw,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=2cm,anchor=north,rotate=270] (b) at (a.north) {};

\node[scale=.5,pair of pants,draw,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=2cm,anchor=north] (c) at (b.north) {};

\end{tikzpicture}` 
but maybe I don't understand properly how nodes work in tikz...

Comment: @tetrapharmakon: From your prior comment, it looks as though you need to look at the details of how TikZ places a node.  In short, saying `\node[anchor=east] (a.north) {};` places the **east** anchor of the **new** node at the same place as the **north** anchor of the **old** node.  The other thing you have to know is that when you rotate a node then the anchors rotate as well, so that `\node[rotate=180] {};` swaps the east and west anchors, and the north and south.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey, This is a fantastic package!  Thank you!

Comment: @Sam: Thanks.  If you have any comments on how to improve it, please let me know.  Either contact me privately or use the "From Answers to Packages" chatroom.  (The comment thread here probably isn't suitable)

Comment: For some reason when I copy the code and compile it the right bended arcs in the pants are not shown...

Comment: @Marion Are you trying the code from this specific answer or are you using the tqft TikZ library (which should be in your TeX distribution, or if not is available from CTAN)?  If the former, then you should use the latter.

Comment: I just copied the code on my Latex file. I apologise, I am completely new at TiKZ so I am not sure what I am supposed to do!

Comment: @Marion That's normally a reasonable thing to do, but in this case then I turned it into a proper TikZ library.  There should be documentation with your distribution, or you could go to ctan or to www.texdoc.net and search for tqft