# Incomplete TQFT diagrams and superfluous space

Tags: tikz-pgf, tqft

I am using Andrew Stacey's package for drawing cobordisms ([see this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17031/topological-quantum-field-theory-diagrams-with-pstricks-or-tikz)), and I have two questions.

**Firstly**, how can I achieve a drawing such as the one below? To be precise, how would I go about creating a **fat** cobordism, where some of the incoming and outgoing **missing boundary pieces**, i.e. not drawn but implied by vertical dots?

[image]

**Secondly**, how do I get rid of the extraspace below the reverse pair of pants? it affects the parantheses

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tqft}
\begin{document}
\[
S_M\left(\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/flow=east]
    \node[draw, tqft, reverse pair of pants, boundary lower style={draw,dashed}] (A) {};
    \node[tqft boundary circle,draw] at (A.outgoing boundary 1) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad\right)=\bullet
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: For Q2, I would try to add `baseline=-0.5ex` (or better see [use of tikzpicture matrix in align or gather environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59660/13304)) to the picture's options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close enough...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{tqft}
\begin{document}
\[
    p\left\{\vphantom{\vrule height80pt}\right.
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=57pt,ultra thick,red]
        \pic[
            tqft,rotate=90,
            cobordism height=70pt,boundary separation=30pt,
            cobordism edge/.style={draw},
            incoming boundary 2/.style={dotted},
            incoming upper boundary component 2/.style={dotted},
            incoming lower boundary component 2/.style={dotted},
            incoming boundary 3/.style={dotted},
            between outgoing 2 and 3/.style={dotted},
            outgoing upper boundary component 2/.style={dotted},
            outgoing lower boundary component 2/.style={dotted},
            between outgoing 1 and 2/.style={dotted},
            incoming boundary components=5,
            outgoing boundary components=4,offset=.5,
            every upper boundary component/.style={draw},
            every lower boundary component/.style={draw,thin},
            genus=3,
            hole 1/.style={rotate=-90,shift={(0pt,130pt)}},
            hole 2/.style={rotate=-90,shift={(-20pt,100pt)}},
            hole 3/.style={rotate=-90,shift={(-60pt,60pt)}},]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \left.\vphantom{\vrule height60pt}\right\}q
\]
\end{document}
```