# Help with drawing tikz diagrams of worldsheet topologies

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikzlibrary

Can someone help me reproduce the following images - or parts of them - with `tikz`. (In case it helps to clarify my intent: I am trying to draw the worldsheet topologies for the vacuum diagram of the oriented open and closed strings at tree- and one-loop-level)?

---

### Open string

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

### Closed string

### [image: ![![enter image description here]

Please excuse my honest but admittedly pathetic attempt to draw them by hand. Perhaps some words can help:

- For the open string, all objects except the cylinder in the lower right should be two-dimensional surfaces on a flat two-dimensional background.
- For the closed string, all surfaces should look like two-dimensional surfaces embedded into three-dimensional space, i.e. convey a perception of depth. The 'hashtags' are only there to illustrate this point and should not appear in the final image. If possible, something akin to the shapes produced for [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70090/3d-helix-torus-with-hidden-lines/70979#70979) question would a great. (Perhaps less flashy, i.e. black/white/gray colors only)
- All shapes should be filled with a light gray.
- After looking at the `tqft` package and seeing its 'cups' I realized these would be much more appropriate for the ends of the closed string worldsheets (see the updated second image).

So far, I started on the disk,

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw (0,0) circle (1);

        \draw [<->] (-0.95,-0.6) arc (-150:-30:1.1);

        \draw [->] (-0.8,-0.3) -- (0.8,-0.3);

        \node at (0,-1.5) {$\tau$};
        \node at (0,-0.5) {$\sigma$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and the cylinder.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]

        \draw[<->] (0.2,3) arc (40:320:0.4 and 2.33);
        \draw (0,0) -- (4,0);
        \draw (0,3) -- (4,3);
        \draw (0,0) arc (270:90:0.3 and 1.5);
        \draw (4,1.5) ellipse (0.5 and 1.5);
        \draw (-0.7,1.5) node {$\tau$};
        \draw[->] (0.5,-0.3) -- (3.5,-0.3);
        \draw (2,-0.5) node {$\sigma$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help! I would more than welcome suggestions or partial solutions.

Comment: What have you done so far to solve this problem? I don't think this platform is existing for outsourcing your work.

Comment: Well, I managed the cylinder and the disk so far, but I didn't get them to exactly resemble the above. I realize this isn't much of a start which is why I haven't included them in my question (yet)...

Comment: You should include at least what you have, otherwise your question leaves the impression, that you're just not motivated to solve your problems by yourself.

Comment: Alright, it's included now. Had to remove some things that weren't working yet.

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{tqft}` would be a good place to start

Comment: @LoopSpace Is there a list of TikZ libraries/extensions anywhere? They are not the easiest things to find.

Comment: There a quite a few examples of torus available here such as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70090/3d-helix-torus-with-hidden-lines/70979?s=1|0.0000#70979, including odd one like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17031/topological-quantum-field-theory-diagrams-with-pstricks-or-tikz

Comment: @cfr [here is at least a starting point](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42611/list-of-available-tikz-libraries-with-a-short-introduction) but not a complete list.

Comment: @JMP Thanks. A list covering 'hidden' libraries and third-party libraries/extensions would be really useful, I think. Not that the list you pointed at is good - it is. But it concentrates on duplicating the listing in the manual, it seems to me ;).

Comment: @cfr There is a tag tikzlibrary existing, which I added to the question (as soon as it is positively reviewed). Probably its a good idea to go through some more questions adding this tag, which hopefully helps finding some specialized libraries at least within this board.

Comment: @JMP Splendid !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So here is a first partial solution. Probably way to complicated. I needed to figure out first, how the tqft package works...

In case I find some time to think about this further, I'll go on working on this...

**Edit**

Some progress, but still room for improvements (simplifying and annotating code...)

**Edit2**

Its more or less done. I leave the fine tuning and customization to you.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tqft}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    {\scriptsize
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every tqft/.append style={transform shape, rotate=90, tqft/circle x radius=7pt, tqft/circle y radius=0pt, tqft/boundary separation=1cm}]
            % cobordism at upper left
            \pic[ 
                 tqft/cylinder to prior,
                 name=a,
                 every outgoing lower boundary component/.style={draw},
                 every incoming  boundary component/.style={draw},
                 cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
                ];
            % annotation of cobordism at upper left
            \coordinate (temp1) at ($(a-incoming  boundary.west)!0.3!(a-outgoing  boundary.west) +(0,0.08)$);
            \coordinate (temp2) at ($(a-incoming  boundary.west)!0.7!(a-outgoing  boundary.west) +(0,-0.08)$);
            \draw[dashed]
            (temp1) node[below] {$\tau_1$} -- +(0,0.5) 
            (temp2) node[below] {$\tau_2$} -- +(0,0.5);
            \draw[->] ($(a-incoming boundary.west) - (0.1,0)$) node[below] {$\sigma$} -- ++(0,0.5);
            \draw (a-outgoing boundary) ++(0.5,0) node {$+$};                       
            \draw[->] ($(a-incoming  boundary.east)+(0.1,0.1)$) to[bend left=13] +(0.9,-0.2);
            \node[above] at ($(a-incoming  boundary.east)+(0.55,0.1)$) {$\tau$};
            %
            % cobordism at upper right consisting of two 'pants'
            \pic[   
                 tqft/pair of pants,
                 name=b,
                 every incoming upper boundary component/.style={draw},
                 every incoming  boundary component/.style={draw},
                 cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
                 at={($(a-outgoing boundary)+(1,0)$)},
                ];
            %
            \pic[
                 tqft/reverse pair of pants,
                 name=c,
                 every outgoing lower boundary component/.style={draw},
                 %every incoming  boundary component/.style={draw},
                 cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
                 at=(b-outgoing boundary 1),
                ];
            %  annotation of cobordism at upper right
            \draw[->] ($(b-incoming boundary.west) - (0.1,0)$) node[below] {$\sigma$} -- ($(b-incoming boundary.east) - (0.1,0)$);
            \coordinate (temp1) at ($(b-between outgoing 1 and 2)!0.2!(c-between incoming 1 and 2) +(0,0.72)$);
            \coordinate (temp2) at ($(b-between outgoing 1 and 2)!0.8!(c-between incoming 1 and 2) +(0,0.72)$);
            \draw[dashed]
            (temp1) node[above] {$\tau_1$} -- +(0,-0.51) ++(0,-0.93) -- ++(0,-0.53)
            (temp2) node[above] {$\tau_2$} -- +(0,-0.51) ++(0,-0.93) -- ++(0,-0.53);
            \draw[->] ($(b-incoming  boundary.east)+(0.1,0.1)$) to[bend right=13] +(0.9,0.25);
            \node[above] at ($(b-incoming  boundary.east)+(0.55,0.1)$) {$\tau$};
            %
            % drawing cylinder
            \path let \p1=(b-between outgoing 1 and 2), \p2=(c-between incoming 1 and 2) in
                node[name=cyl1,shape=ellipse, minimum height=.3cm, minimum width={\x2-\x1},draw, outer sep=0] 
                at ($(b-outgoing boundary 1)-(0,2.5)$) {}
                node[name=rec,shape=rectangle, minimum height=1cm, minimum width={\x2-\x1}, fill=white, anchor=south] 
                at (cyl1) {}
                node[name=cyl2,shape=ellipse, minimum height=.3cm, minimum width={\x2-\x1}, fill=white,draw, outer sep=0] 
                at (rec.north) {}
                ;
            \draw (cyl1.west) -- (cyl2.west) (cyl1.east) -- (cyl2.east);
            % annotating cylinder
            \draw[<->] ($(cyl2.north east)+(0,0.1)$) to[bend right=15] ($(cyl2.north west)+(0,0.1)$);
            \node[left] at ($(cyl2.north west)+(0,0.1)$) {$\tau$};
            \draw[->] (cyl1.south east) ++ (0.3,0.1) -- ++(0,1.2);
            \draw (cyl1.south east) ++ (0.3,0.7) node [right] {$\sigma$};
            \draw[dashed] ($(cyl1.west)!0.2!(cyl1.east) +(0,-0.12)$) node[below] {$\tau_1$} --($(cyl2.west)!0.2!(cyl2.east) +(0,0.12)$) 
            ($(cyl1.west)!0.8!(cyl1.east) +(0,-0.12)$) node[below] {$\tau_2$} --($(cyl2.west)!0.8!(cyl2.east) +(0,0.12)$);
            \draw (cyl2) ++(85:0.9) -- +(0,-0.4) (cyl2) ++(95:0.9) -- +(0,-0.4);
            % drawing and annotating circle
            \node[draw, shape=circle, minimum width=1cm]
            at (cyl2.west -| a-between first incoming and first outgoing)  (circ){};
            \draw[dashed] (circ) +(155:0.5) -- +(25:0.5) node[right] {$\tau_2$}
            +(205:0.5) -- +(335:0.5) node[right] {$\tau_1$};
            \draw[->] (circ) +(205:0.35) -- +(335:0.35);
            \node[below=-0.3em] at(circ) {$\sigma$};
            \draw (circ) ++(85:0.9) -- +(0,0.4) (circ) ++(95:0.9) -- +(0,0.4);
            \draw[<->] (circ.south west) +(-0.1,0) to[bend left=45] ($(circ.north west)+(-0.1,0)$);
            \node[left] at(circ.west) {$\tau$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tqft}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
{\scriptsize
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every tqft/.append style={transform shape, rotate=90, tqft/circle x radius=7pt, tqft/boundary separation=1cm, tqft/view from=incoming}]
      % cobordism at upper left
        \pic[ 
              tqft/cylinder to prior,
              name=a,
              every incoming lower boundary component/.style={draw},
              every outgoing lower boundary component/.style={draw},
              cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
             ];
        \pic[
              tqft/cup,
              cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
              at=(a-outgoing boundary),
             ];
        % annotation of cobordism at upper left
        \coordinate (temp1) at ($(a-incoming  boundary.west)!0.3!(a-outgoing  boundary.west) +(0,0.08)$);
        \coordinate (temp2) at ($(a-incoming  boundary.west)!0.7!(a-outgoing  boundary.west) +(0,-0.08)$);
        \draw[dashed]
        (temp1) node[below] {$\tau_1$} to[bend right=40] ++(0,0.5) 
        (temp2) node[below] {$\tau_2$} to[bend left=40] ++(0,0.5);
        \draw[->] ($(a-incoming boundary.west) - (0.2,0)$) node[below] {$\sigma$} to[bend left=40] ++(0,0.5);
        \draw (a-outgoing boundary) ++(0.85,0) node {$+$};                      
        \draw[->] ($(a-incoming  boundary.east)+(0.1,0.1)$) to[bend left=13] +(0.9,-0.2);
        \node[above] at ($(a-incoming  boundary.east)+(0.55,0.1)$) {$\tau$};
        %
        % cobordism at upper right consisting of two 'pants' and a cup
        \pic[   
              tqft/pair of pants,
              name=b,
              every incoming lower boundary component/.style={draw},
              cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
              at={($(a-outgoing boundary)+(1.5,0)$)},
             ];
         %
         \pic[
              tqft/reverse pair of pants,
              name=c,
              every outgoing lower boundary component/.style={draw},
              cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
              at=(b-outgoing boundary 1),
             ];
        \pic[
              tqft/cup,
              cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
              at=(c-outgoing boundary),
             ];
        %  annotation of cobordism at upper right
        \draw[->] ($(b-incoming boundary.west) - (0.2,0)$) node[below] {$\sigma$}  to[bend left=40] ++(0,0.5);
        \coordinate (temp1) at ($(b-between outgoing 1 and 2)!0.2!(c-between incoming 1 and 2) +(0,0.72)$);
        \coordinate (temp2) at ($(b-between outgoing 1 and 2)!0.8!(c-between incoming 1 and 2) +(0,0.72)$);
        \draw[dashed]
        (temp1) node[above] {$\tau_1$} to[bend left=40] +(0,-0.51) ++(0,-0.93) to[bend right=40] ++(0,-0.42)
        (temp2) node[above] {$\tau_2$} to[bend right=40] +(0,-0.51) ++(0,-0.93) to[bend left=40] ++(0,-0.42);
        \draw[->] ($(b-incoming  boundary.east)+(0.1,0.1)$) to[bend right=13] +(0.9,0.25);
        \node[above] at ($(b-incoming  boundary.east)+(0.55,0.1)$) {$\tau$};
        %
        %drawing ring
        \pic[
              tqft ,
              name=d,
              incoming boundary components=0,
              outgoing boundary components=2,
              cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
              anchor=between outgoing 1 and 2,
              at={($(b-between outgoing 1 and 2)!0!(c-between incoming 1 and 2) - (0,2.5)$)},
             ];

        \pic[
              tqft ,
              name=e,
              incoming boundary components=2,
              outgoing boundary components=0,
              cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
              at = {(d-outgoing boundary 1)},
             ];
        \coordinate (temp1) at ($(d-between outgoing 1 and 2)!0.2!(e-between incoming 1 and 2) +(0,0.72)$);
        \coordinate (temp2) at ($(d-between outgoing 1 and 2)!0.8!(e-between incoming 1 and 2) +(0,0.72)$);
        \draw[dashed]
        (temp1) to[bend left=40] +(0,-0.51) ++(0,-0.93) node[below] {$\tau_1$} to[bend right=40] ++(0,-0.42) 
        (temp2) to[bend right=40] +(0,-0.51) ++(0,-0.93) node[below] {$\tau_2$} to[bend left=40] ++(0,-0.42);
        %
        \coordinate (temp1) at ($(d-between outgoing 1 and 2)!0.5!(e-between incoming 1 and 2)$);
        \coordinate (temp2) at (a-between first incoming and first outgoing);
        \draw[->] ($(e-incoming boundary 2)+(-1.1,-0.3)$) node[above left] {$\tau$} to[bend left=30] +(0.7,0.6);
        \draw [->] ($(d-between outgoing 1 and 2) + (-0.45,0)$) node [below right] {$\sigma$} to[bend left=40] +(0.4,0);
        \draw (temp1) ++(-0.075,1.5) -- ++(0,-0.4) ++(0.15,0) -- +(0,0.4);
        %
        % drawing and annotating ball
        \node[draw, shape=circle, minimum width=1.5cm]
        at (temp1-|temp2)  (circ){};
        \draw[dashed] (circ) +(265:0.75) node[below] {$\tau_2$} to[bend left=15] +(95:0.75);
        \draw[dashed] (circ) +(295:0.75) to[bend right=40] +(65:0.75) node[right] {$\tau_1$};
        \draw[->] (circ) +(220:0.5) to[bend left=20] +(140:0.5);
        \node[right] at(circ.west) {$\sigma$};
        \draw (circ) ++(-0.075,1.5) -- ++(0,-0.4) ++(0.15,0) -- +(0,0.4);
        \draw[<->] (circ.south west) +(-0.1,0) to[bend left=45] ($(circ.north west)+(-0.1,0)$);
        \node[left=0.25em] at(circ.west) {$\tau$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is just a comment so that if you have questions about the tqft package you can use the `@` invocation to draw my attention to them.

Comment: @LoopSpace actually I got one. How is the `cobordism height` key actually used? Is there also an option to scale the width of the cobordism? I did this by scaling the x dimension. I am not too happy yet, how the output looks like.

Comment: The `cobordism height` is the "height" between the line of incoming bdry and outgoing bdry components.  As you're rotating your diagrams, that's the width as you have it.  So that key should be what you're looking for for the scaling.  The initial value is 2cm, so you could try setting it to 1cm and see if that helps.

Comment: @LoopSpace I actually meant how to apply it in the syntax of the code.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood! Actually, you don't want `cobordism height`, you want `circle x radius` and `boundary separation`.  Inside the `every tqft/.append style` put `tqft/circle x radius=5pt,tqft/boundary separation=1cm`.

Comment: @JMP This a a great start! Some comments in case you _do_ work on it some more: I edited my answer to include images in which the `tau` labels are properly subscripted. The reason they weren't initially is that I couldn't figure out a way to do this in Mac's preview (which I used to draw this by hand). If you move on to the closed string worldsheets: they should look three-dimensional. In particular, the 'hashtags' I put on them are only there to give an idea of their curvature and shouldn't appear in the final image. Please see the new comment below the image for clarification.

Comment: @LoopSpace do you have any idea what happens to the naming scheme of the nodes, when there is either `incoming boundary components=0` or `outgoing boundary components=0` ?

Comment: @JMP If there aren't any boundary components of a particular type then there aren't any nodes at those points.  But the other nodes should be there and named as normally.

Answer (score 5):

I have a partial drawing which I can't complete right now due to time constraints. I will however provide you with the source material and the method. First, the result:

[image]

Second, the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{c969696}{RGB}{150,150,150}


\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt, x=0.80pt, yscale=-1.000000, xscale=1.000000, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
  \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
    (136.0000,309.3622) node[above right] (text7388) {};
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd
    rule,line width=1.600pt] (77.5000,207.3622) .. controls (77.5000,207.3622) and
    (110.0000,190.9336) .. (148.5714,205.2193) .. controls (187.1429,219.5051) and
    (208.7425,214.4305) .. (223.6940,203.7295) .. controls (233.6455,203.3856) and
    (228.5209,245.6607) .. (228.7373,255.3927) .. controls (241.8109,255.1247) and
    (229.6429,260.9336) .. (229.6429,260.9336) .. controls (229.6429,260.9336) and
    (189.2857,273.4336) .. (155.0000,257.3622) .. controls (120.7143,241.2908) and
    (87.5000,261.6479) .. (87.5000,261.6479) .. controls (62.3709,241.8132) and
    (67.6883,224.4083) .. (77.5000,207.3622) -- cycle;

    %%%%%%%%% DASHED LINES
  \path[draw=black,dash pattern=on 9.54pt off 9.54pt,line join=miter,line
    cap=butt,miter limit=1.00,even odd rule,line width=0.795pt]
    (192.1789,264.9757) .. controls (204.8876,266.3769) and (204.5955,215.0655) ..
    (192.6842,214.6613) -- (192.6842,214.6613) -- (192.6842,214.6613);

    \path[draw=black,dash pattern=on 9.34pt off 9.34pt,line join=miter,line
    cap=butt,miter limit=1.00,even odd rule,line width=0.779pt]
    (139.1379,251.9081) .. controls (151.8670,253.2510) and (151.5745,204.0758) ..
    (139.6440,203.6884) -- (139.6440,203.6884) -- (139.6440,203.6884);


   %%%%%%%%%% ARROWS 
  \path[->,draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,even odd rule,line width=0.800pt]
    (85.2064,198.8843) .. controls (94.9900,193.8625) and (116.2613,191.8955) ..
    (129.0470,196.0559);
  \path[->,draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd
    rule,line width=0.800pt] (70.7485,255.6590) .. controls (61.4904,246.2335) and
    (59.2061,224.9889) .. (68.4835,211.7704);

    \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd
    rule,line width=1.600pt] (94.7523,234.2397) .. controls (99.2549,215.8434) and
    (111.4350,211.0672) .. (127.9863,209.4909);
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd
    rule,line width=1.600pt] (108.5409,241.3107) .. controls (115.4510,226.6988)
    and (123.3950,219.7274) .. (138.5929,220.4511);
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd
    rule,line width=1.600pt] (100.4092,208.4303) .. controls (118.7277,206.4666)
    and (130.3307,218.6267) .. (135.4110,234.5932);
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd
    rule,line width=1.600pt] (87.3277,220.0975) .. controls (106.6494,218.1132)
    and (117.6898,228.9131) .. (123.3901,245.1998);

    %%%% Ellipse
  \path[draw=black,fill=c969696,line join=round,line cap=round,miter
    limit=4.00,line width=1.600pt] (228.2945,231.2868) ellipse (0.3993cm and
    0.8303cm);



  \path[xscale=0.963,yscale=1.038,fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line
    width=0.800pt] (101.3132,184.9408) node[above right] (text7156) {$\tau$};
  \path[xscale=0.963,yscale=1.038,fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line
    width=0.800pt] (52.7323,228.9850) node[above right] (text7162) {$\sigma$};
  \path[xscale=0.963,yscale=1.038,fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line
    width=0.800pt] (139.2488,255.7794) node[above right] (text7166) {$\tau_1$};
  \path[xscale=0.963,yscale=1.038,fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line
    width=0.800pt] (197.3631,267.3572) node[above right] (text7170) {$\tau_2$};
  \path[fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line width=0.800pt]
    (274.0000,238.3622) node[above right] (text7384) {$+$};
  \path[cm={{0.0,1.0,-1.0,0.0,(0.0,0.0)}},fill=black,line join=miter,line
    cap=butt,line width=0.800pt] (279.1168,-135.8970) node[above right] (text7392)
    {$=$};
  \path[cm={{0.0,1.0,-1.0,0.0,(0.0,0.0)}},fill=black,line join=miter,line
    cap=butt,line width=0.800pt] (310.1168,-449.8970) node[above right] (text7396)
    {$=$};
  \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line
    width=1.600pt] (139.0000,422.3622) ellipse (2.0602cm and 2.1167cm);
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd
    rule,line width=1.600pt] (126.0000,376.8622) .. controls (155.2079,375.3357)
    and (182.8903,392.2794) .. (189.5000,421.3622);
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd
    rule,line width=1.600pt] (179.5000,379.3622) .. controls (156.9263,385.7430)
    and (143.0268,396.4286) .. (135.0000,419.3622);
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd
    rule,line width=1.600pt] (185.5000,392.3622) .. controls (165.0696,397.9739)
    and (153.6168,409.2724) .. (146.0000,427.3622);
  \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd
    rule,line width=1.600pt] (174.4759,416.3600) .. controls (171.2596,393.2586)
    and (148.1356,388.9491) .. (128.5029,389.8962);

    %%%%% dashed pattern
  \path[draw=black,dash pattern=on 9.97pt off 9.97pt,line join=miter,line
    cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd rule,line width=0.831pt]
    (136.6636,347.8792) .. controls (103.8299,350.8115) and (107.5788,492.0596) ..
    (142.5002,496.8452);
  \path[draw=black,dash pattern=on 9.60pt off 9.60pt,line join=miter,line
    cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,even odd rule,line width=0.800pt]
    (176.0000,357.3622) .. controls (193.9175,369.8639) and (198.6504,468.7237) ..
    (174.5000,488.3622);

    %%%% arrows
  \path[->,draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,even odd rule,line width=0.800pt]
    (89.0000,358.3622) .. controls (120.2581,338.8624) and (151.0718,333.1351) ..
    (181.0000,354.8622);
  \path[xscale=0.963,yscale=1.038,fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line
    width=0.800pt] (106.5045,328.9305) node[above right] (text7438) {$\tau$};
  \path[->, draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,even odd rule,line width=0.800pt]
    (103.5000,480.8622) .. controls (103.5000,480.8622) and (82.5000,415.8622) ..
    (102.0000,367.3622);
  \path[xscale=0.963,yscale=1.038,fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line
    width=0.800pt] (82.3229,409.0926) node[above right] (text7444) {$\sigma$};
  \path[xscale=0.963,yscale=1.038,fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line
    width=0.800pt] (130.4235,490.3046) node[above right] (text7448) {$\tau_1$};
  \path[xscale=0.963,yscale=1.038,fill=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,line
    width=0.800pt] (181.7891,477.3222) node[above right] (text7452) {$\tau_2$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Finally, how. I drew over your sketch in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org), then used [svg2tikz](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz) to output TikZ code.

[Here](http://cl.ly/0I39343W2B2T) is my .svg file if you wish to continue with this file; you will need to fiddle slightly with the end result (e.g. arrows lose their heads)