# Issues when trying to move a tikz pic composition

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, tqft

I am trying to construct a certain topological structure for my paper. Up until now my focus was primarily on typesetting (AKA I'm not very skilled at certain portions of `tikz`). I managed to break through and comprehend some of the more complex code given in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302682/help-with-drawing-tikz-diagrams-of-worldsheet-topologies) very helpful TEX.SX thread. This is my MWE so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tqft}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every tqft/.append style={transform shape, rotate=0, tqft/circle x radius=7pt, tqft/circle y radius=3pt, tqft/boundary separation=1.3cm}]
\pic[   
tqft/pair of pants,
name=b,
every incoming upper boundary component/.style={draw},
every incoming  boundary component/.style={draw},
cobordism  edge/.style={draw}
];
\pic[
tqft/reverse pair of pants,
name=c,
every outgoing lower boundary component/.style={draw},
cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
at=(b-outgoing boundary 1),
];
\node at (0,-4.5) {$\vdots$};
\pic[   
tqft/pair of pants,
name=d,
every incoming upper boundary component/.style={draw},
every incoming  boundary component/.style={draw},
cobordism  edge/.style={draw}
];
\pic[
tqft/reverse pair of pants,
name=e,
every outgoing lower boundary component/.style={draw},
cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
at=(b-outgoing boundary 2),
% at=(0,-6.5),
];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives me this quazi-shape:

[image]

I am aware that this is due to the definitions of the boundaries, so I tried to switch to a coordinate approach, which you can see commented out underneath, and for a very good reason. If I were to compile my code with the commented line (of course the latter would replace `at=(b-outgoing boundary 2),`) the compilation itself would never be completed.

**I ask you to show me a suitable method of positioning the compositions in the `pic` environment by coordinates, similar to my endeavour, of course.** And I also warmly ask you to fix one more little detail: at the bottom of the topological construct we see the enter to the "tube"; I'd like another half of the ellipse *behind* the construct to denote that this particular part is covered and to give a sense of "3D" perspective. The "height" of the ellipse is accommodate by changing the `y` value in `tikzpicture`'s preamble, but I have no idea how to achieve the dashed part.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package author has done something rather unhelpful in setting up a non-standard syntax for the package's `pic`s. This breaks the usual `pic` syntax, including the `\pic at ...` which is usually used to place them. However, you can use coordinates with the non-standard syntax provided. You just need to surround the coordinate by curly brackets. For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tqft}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    every tqft/.append style={%
      transform shape,
      rotate=0,
      tqft/circle x radius=7pt,
      tqft/circle y radius=3pt,
      tqft/boundary separation=1.3cm
    },
  ]
  \pic [
  tqft/pair of pants,
  name=b,
  every incoming upper boundary component/.style={draw},
  every incoming  boundary component/.style={draw},
  cobordism  edge/.style={draw}
  ];
  \pic[
  tqft/reverse pair of pants,
  name=c,
  every outgoing lower boundary component/.style={draw},
  cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
  at=(b-outgoing boundary 1),
  ];
  \node at (0,-4.5) {$\vdots$};
  \pic[
  tqft/pair of pants,
  name=d,
  every incoming upper boundary component/.style={draw},
  every incoming  boundary component/.style={draw},
  cobordism  edge/.style={draw}
  ];
  \pic[
  tqft/reverse pair of pants,
  name=e,
  every outgoing lower boundary component/.style={draw},
  cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
%   at=(b-outgoing boundary 2),
  at={(0,-6.5)},
  ];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

works fine.

[image: placing deviant <code>pic</code> with coordinates]

You can draw the other halves of the ellipses by using the `every boundary component` style. For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tqft}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    every tqft/.append style={%
      transform shape,
      rotate=0,
      tqft/circle x radius=7pt,
      tqft/circle y radius=3pt,
      tqft/boundary separation=1.3cm,
      tqft/every boundary component/.style={draw, densely dashed, opacity=.5}
    },
  ]
  \pic [
  tqft/pair of pants,
  name=b,
  every incoming upper boundary component/.style={draw},
  every incoming  boundary component/.style={draw},
  cobordism  edge/.style={draw}
  ];
  \pic[
  tqft/reverse pair of pants,
  name=c,
  every outgoing lower boundary component/.style={draw},
  cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
  at=(b-outgoing boundary 1),
  ];
  \node at (0,-4.5) {$\vdots$};
  \pic[
  tqft/pair of pants,
  name=d,
  every incoming upper boundary component/.style={draw},
  every incoming  boundary component/.style={draw},
  cobordism  edge/.style={draw}
  ];
  \pic[
  tqft/reverse pair of pants,
  name=e,
  every outgoing lower boundary component/.style={draw},
  cobordism  edge/.style={draw},
%   at=(b-outgoing boundary 2),
  at={(0,-6.5)},
  ];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: with 3D gestures]

Comment: All the praise to you, sir! I couldn't be more grateful. One big tick and an upvote can't even begin to express the gratitude I feel right now!

Comment: @GregorPerčič Thanks, but please don't make assumptions. My username is 'cfr'. What makes you so sure I'm male?

Comment: I hope I didn't offend you. I generally use the phrase "praise to you, sir" to express my gratitude. It's true though that most of my mathematics colleagues are male (for some reason every woman I know hates mathematics, but I won't blatantly generalise; surely there are women that have achieved academic peaks in mathematics; Mary Lucy Cartwright is one of them, for example).

Comment: @GregorPerčič Not really offend. I'm used to it, I guess. (But I'm determined not to *accept* it ;).)

Comment: Well, I'm very glad to hear that! :)

Comment: Bit late to this one.  I've logged it at https://github.com/loopspace/TQFT/issues/1  In my defence, `pic`s were very new when I ported the original tqft code from nodes to pics and many of my design choices were influenced by the original node syntax.

Comment: @LoopSpace Hindsight is 20:20. Maybe your crystal ball needs a service?

Comment: @cfr `\usepackage{crystalball} \polish{crystal}`

Comment: @LoopSpace We need that package.